# How can I sort data by category to and from a facebook page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to sort posts from a facebook page by category or tags. Is there any way I can post and retrieve data sorted by categories? This is my concept:

I want to post with a tag name "general_discussions":

```
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com/fb_page/feed/?access_token='+sess.accessToken,{
    "message": "The content of the post",
    "tag": "general_discussions" //just an example
},function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
});
```

...and to sort all posts with "tag": "general_discussion", I do this:

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/fb_page/feed/?tag=general_discussions&access_token='+sess.accessToken,function(resp){
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Is there a way on facebook to do somethingt like that?

Comment: No, Facebook does not offer any “tagging” functionality of that kind.

Comment: Is there any other thing i can do to sort the posts of a page by category?